# How to convert my Graphics.Drawline drawing on panel, to saved image?

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

I have a panel called "canvas".  It is transparent.  So the background is from the form image, which is dark blue.  This shows in the panel or canvas.

When I save the canvas to image, it saves the background, but not what I have drawn thereon, my drawline pen is yellow.  And I can see it drawing on the panel.  But when I save it... there are not yellow lines in the image.

What am I missing?  Where are my yellow lines?

I am running this with my timer tick... to get the view to update.
This tracks the position of a CNC type machine. Gives a visual of where
the machine is in relation to Zero.

My ultimate goal, is to have a "viewport" that is zoomable, thus getting it
into a image, for easy resizing, and displaying in a pictureBox, which will
handle the stretched image and center it automatically?

I have read some complex solutions, but I am after the simple ones.
Any help would be appreciated.  Sincerely,

---

```
private void VMoveNow()//Draw on panel called "canvas".
{
    double a = GV.MYa * -1; //Change Direction of Y Drawing.
    xc = Convert.ToInt32(GV.MXa) + (canvas.Width / 2);
    yc = Convert.ToInt32(a) + (canvas.Height / 2);
    g = canvas.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawLine(p, x, y, xc, yc);
    x = xc;
    y = yc;
    g.Dispose();
}
private void SaveBMP() 
{
    try
    {
        Bitmap mybmp = new Bitmap(canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
        canvas.DrawToBitmap(mybmp, canvas.Bounds);
        mybmp.Save("C:\\myimage.bmp");
    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Never use CreateGraphics(), always use the Paint event.  Note how simply minimizing and restoring the window also makes you lose the pixels.

Comment: Thanks Hans,  I am using a locked form, and fixed panel, locked in place as well, all min and max turned off.  So the form and panel never get moved or resized.  Thus I am not having a problem with the CreateGraphics.  As well by dealing with my var ahead of time... my sizing, zooming or scaling, is working as desired. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for looking.

I answered my own problem, after several attempts... I have figured out that I can scale my var's used for this drawings... and the size of the Drawline will be scale as a result.

So I now have scaling of the Drawline drawing, in a panel, with no picture or picture box needed.  Does what I wished.

Setting the Pen width to -1 takes care of it resizing.